# Criar classes de produtos e fotos e inicializa

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, classes, lista

Tenho uma classe `Produto` e dentro dessa classe tenho uma classe `Categoria` e uma Classe `Foto`.

**1 Produto pode ter apenas 1 categoria, porém pode ter várias Fotos.**

O problema é com as fotos.

Fiz assim:

```
 public class Produto
 {
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Foto> Fotos { get; set; }
 }

public class Categoria
{
    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
}

public class Foto
{
    public int FotoId { get; set; }
    public string Foto { get; set; }
    public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }
}
```

E chamo elas assim:

```
var produtos = new List<Produto>();
var prod = new Produto { Categoria = new Categoria()};

var foto = new Foto
{
    NomeFoto = "Csa.jhpg"
};
prod.Fotos.Add(foto); // <============= ERRO AQUI
foto = new Foto
{
    NomeFoto = "foto2.jpg"
};
prod.Nome = "nome produto";
prod.Categoria.nome = "categoria de teste";

prod.Fotos.Add(foto);
produtos.Add(prod);
```

Apresentando o erro:

> A referência a um objeto não está definida para uma instância do objeto.
>   na linha: `prod.Fotos.Add(foto); //ERRO AQUI`

Comment: Qual é a dúvida?

Comment: da erro no código quando faço o insert da Foto.ADD

Comment: A tag `java` não deveria ser retirada?

Comment: coloquei java pois a sintaxe para isso é idêntica, a resposta do bigtown claro que não funcionaria (acho), mas fique a vontade de remover caso ache melhor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

você precisa iniciar a coleção antes de poder usa-la, para tal modifique o construtor de `Produto`.

```
public class Produto
{
    public Produto() 
    {
        this.Fotos = new HashSet<Foto>();
    }

    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Foto> Fotos { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: funcionou, teria como eu inicializar quando faço o var prod = new Produto { Categoria = new Categoria()}; ao invés de direto na classe? só por curiosidade

Comment: sim, é possível, mas para este tipo de estrutura, o ideal é faze-lo no construtor mesmo.

Answer (score 4):

Já sabe como solucionar o problema, vou complementar que o ideal não é fazer a inicialização no construtor. [Isto deve ser evitado sempre que possível, nem sempre é](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Neste caso eu faria o recomendável se estiver usando o C# 6 ([mais organizado e não perde nada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108516/101)):

```
public class Produto {
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Foto> Fotos { get; set; } = new List<Foto>;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Product.cs).

Caso não esteja usando o C# 6 isto não é possível. Antes só variáveis de instância podiam ser inicializadas. Neste caso ou teria que criar uma propriedade manual para inicializar a variável que guarda o estado da propriedade, ou fazer no construtor mesmo. Depende do caso pode ser melhor um ou outro.

Claro que inicializar depois do objeto construído é menos ideal ainda. Esta recomendação é válida para inicialização dentro da classe, quando a instância é construída automaticamente. Ainda que existam caso onde a inicialização de algum membro possa ser feita depois do objeto construído, isto é raro e deve ser evitado. Só fazer com grande justificativa.

Note que se for para inicializar membros depois que o objeto foi construído, aí raramente é a solução correta. Ou usa o inicializador padrão na classe (a preferida), ou usa a sintaxe de inicialização durante a declaração da variável que sustentará o objeto (boa quando a anterior não é possível ou desejável), ou faz no construtor. Se deixar um membro sem inicializar já na construção, tenha certeza que isto é algo importante para aplicação, caso contrário inicialize antes.

Comment: estou usando o C#6, não sei se devo ou não mudar para esse padrão, preciso ler o link e ver se entendo 100%. porém creio que mudar não fará mal..rs

Comment: Eu diria que é quase certo que pode usar. Se deve é um pouco mais complicado dizer. Não estou vendo uma situação que o construtor seria útil aí. A classe é muito simples. E duvido que ela se torne complicado ao ponto de exigir um. O construtor é para casos onde a inicialização deve ser feita com critérios muito complexos, de forma condicional, ou precisa ser em ordem específica. Se já tivesse um construtor por outro motivo. Isto poderia ser diferente.

Comment: Quando diz que "o ideal **não** é fazer a inicialização no construtor" quer dizer que o estado inicial do objecto deve ser feito recorrendo a *setters* ou à atribuição de valores às propriedades após a construção? E que no caso de listas é melhor que ela seja nula do que vazia?

Comment: @ramaral Digo que deve fazer com inicialização, ou nas variáveis, ou na propriedade (C# 6 em diante). Esta é a forma simples de fazer. A forma complicada é com construtor. Ela é necessária em alguns casos. Mas não deve fazer após a construção. Aí seria um erro. E se for necessário, é um dos motivos para usar o construtor. Isto está explicado na pergunta que eu *linkei*. De maneira alguma eu acho que a lista deve ser nula. Evito isto como o diabo foge da cruz, ainda que muito eventualmente eu possa fazer, se for realmente útil. Bem raro.

Comment: Eu sei que era isso que você pensa mas, no caso concreto desta pergunta, a frase "o ideal não é fazer a inicialização no construtor" dá ideia do contrário. Já agora sabe me dizer se em termos de código "compilado"(C#6) há alguma diferença entre criar a lista no construtor ou na declaração da propriedade?

Comment: No caso concreto eu faria desta forma da minha resposta, a não ser que não estivesse usando o 6, que não é o caso do AP e nunca será o meu :P   Idealmente realmente é assim, só se tiver um bom motivo para usar o construtor. Vive tendo bons motivos, não nesse caso. Melhorei a resposta. Está bom? Obrigado pela "reclamação" :) Vou pesquisar sobre isto, eu acho que se não tiver que fazer nada especial, dá no mesmo. Pode ser uma pergunta interessante a se fazer.