# Nova funcionalidade do C# 6 "Auto-property initializers" é apenas um facilitador?

Tags: c#, .net, propriedade, inicialização

Uma da novas [funcionalidades do C#6](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/new-features-in-c-6) é a possibilidade de inicializar propriedades na altura da declaração.

```
public class Customer
{
    public string First { get; set; } = "Jane";
    public string Last { get; set; } = "Doe";
}
```

O objectivo é apenas facilitar a escrita da classe, como por exemplo deixar de ser necessário declarar um construtor para fazer as inicializações, ou trás algo mais?

Comment: ramaral, será que deveríamos trocar essa tag pela tag `c#`? http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4421/18246

Comment: @jbueno De facto hesitei em colocá-la quando ela não apareceu nas sugestões. A leitura do poste que indicou não me ajudou a decidir, principalmente numa questão tão especifica como esta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tanto as propriedades automáticas disponíveis desde o C# 2, quanto a inicialização delas disponível desde a versão 6 são apenas açúcares sintáticos. Dá no mesmo criar a propriedade de forma mais "manual" e inicializá-la em um construtor.

Claro que se for  mais fundo a própria propriedade é apenas um par de métodos com características específicas, mas vamos ficar nesta primeira camada de abstração.

Quando você escreve

```
class Exemplo {
    public int valor { get; set; } = 1;
}
```

No fundo é o mesmo que

```
internal class Exemplo {
    private int valor;
    public int Valor {
        get { return valor; }
        set { valor = value; }
    }
    public Exemplo() {
        valor = 1;
    }
}
```

De fato o compilador gera um código próximo disto:

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit AutoPropertyInitializer.Exemplo
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object {
  .field private int32 '<Property>k__Valor'
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  .method public hidebysig specialname instance int32 
          get_Valor() cil managed {
              //corpo aqui
          }

  .method public hidebysig specialname instance void
          set_Valor(int32 'value') cil managed {
              //corpo aqui
          }

  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
          instance void  .ctor() cil managed {
              // Code size       18 (0x12)
              .maxstack  8
              IL_0000:  ldarg.0
              IL_0001:  ldc.i4     0x1
              IL_0006:  stfld      int32 AutoPropertyInitializer.Exemplo::'<Property>k__Valor'
              IL_000b:  ldarg.0
              IL_000c:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
              IL_0011:  ret
          }

    .property instance int32 Valor() {
        .get instance int32 AutoPropertyInitializer.Exemplo::get_Valor()
        .set instance void AutoPropertyInitializer.Exemplo::set_Valor(int32)
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/InitDefault.cs).

Comment: Esta nova funcionalidade faz sentido porque assim todas as "variáveis" podem ser inicializadas na declaração.

Answer (score 9):

> O objectivo é apenas facilitar a escrita da classe, como por exemplo deixar de ser necessário declarar um construtor para fazer as inicializações, ou trás algo mais?

Na verdade deixar de ser necessário declarar construtor**es**. Inicialização de variáveis já eram feitas num contexto estático. Agora a linguagem abriu possibilidade para inicialização de propriedades também.