# Como funciona a inicialização de campos em construtores?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, construtor

Na documentação do C# está escrito:

> If a class does not have a constructor, a default constructor is automatically generated and default values are used to initialize the object fields

Ou seja, se uma classe não tem um construtor, um construtor padrão é automaticamente gerado e valores padrões são atribuídos aos campos da classe.
Mas, e se eu declarar um construtor sem parâmetros (em que acredito ser um construtor padrão), parece que ele ainda inicializa os campos para o seu valor padrão, exemplo:

```
    public class SimpleClass
    {
        public int Number { get; private set; }

        public SimpleClass()
        {

        }

        public void Increment()
        {
            Number++;
        }

    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SimpleClass sc = new SimpleClass();
        sc.Increment();
        Console.WriteLine(sc.Number); // Mostra: 1
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Mas isto é inválido:

```
    int i;
    i++;
```

Por que?

Comment: O que você diz ser inválido, na verdade é válido.Tem alguma confusão aí?

Comment: Acho que você confundiu construtor com método.  `public SimpleClass()` é seu construtor ,  `public void Increment()` é seu método, no seu `Main` você faz uma instancia da sua classe e chama o seu método e incrementa sua variável isso faz com que `Number` seja igual a 1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Talvez a melhor forma de ver isso é analisar o código [CIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language):

```
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
.assembly '510a4553-ce16-420a-a407-708c596fefd2'
{
  .hash algorithm 0x00008004
  .ver 0:0:0:0
}
.module '510a4553-ce16-420a-a407-708c596fefd2.dll'
// MVID: {CA762240-7FEE-4C94-8DA0-A08E521CA6D0}
.imagebase 0x10000000
.file alignment 0x00000200
.stackreserve 0x00100000
.subsystem 0x0003       // WINDOWS_CUI
.corflags 0x00000001    //  ILONLY
// Image base: 0x01140000


// =============== CLASS MEMBERS DECLARATION ===================

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit Program
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
  .method public hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  1
    .locals init (class SimpleClass V_0)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  newobj     instance void SimpleClass::.ctor()
    IL_0006:  stloc.0
    IL_0007:  ldloc.0
    IL_0008:  callvirt   instance void SimpleClass::Increment()
    IL_000d:  nop
    IL_000e:  ldloc.0
    IL_000f:  callvirt   instance int32 SimpleClass::get_Number()
    IL_0014:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
    IL_0019:  nop
    IL_001a:  call       valuetype [mscorlib]System.ConsoleKeyInfo [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadKey()
    IL_001f:  pop
    IL_0020:  ret
  } // end of method Program::Main

  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
          instance void  .ctor() cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    IL_0006:  nop
    IL_0007:  ret
  } // end of method Program::.ctor

} // end of class Program

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit SimpleClass
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
  .field private int32 '<Number>k__BackingField'
  .method public hidebysig specialname instance int32 
          get_Number() cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  1
    .locals init (int32 V_0)
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  ldfld      int32 SimpleClass::'<Number>k__BackingField'
    IL_0006:  stloc.0
    IL_0007:  br.s       IL_0009

    IL_0009:  ldloc.0
    IL_000a:  ret
  } // end of method SimpleClass::get_Number

  .method private hidebysig specialname instance void 
          set_Number(int32 'value') cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  ldarg.1
    IL_0002:  stfld      int32 SimpleClass::'<Number>k__BackingField'
    IL_0007:  br.s       IL_0009

    IL_0009:  ret
  } // end of method SimpleClass::set_Number

  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
          instance void  .ctor() cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    IL_0006:  nop
    IL_0007:  nop
    IL_0008:  ret
  } // end of method SimpleClass::.ctor

  .method public hidebysig instance void 
          Increment() cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  3
    .locals init (int32 V_0)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldarg.0
    IL_0002:  call       instance int32 SimpleClass::get_Number()
    IL_0007:  stloc.0
    IL_0008:  ldarg.0
    IL_0009:  ldloc.0
    IL_000a:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_000b:  add
    IL_000c:  call       instance void SimpleClass::set_Number(int32)
    IL_0011:  nop
    IL_0012:  ret
  } // end of method SimpleClass::Increment

  .property instance int32 Number()
  {
    .get instance int32 SimpleClass::get_Number()
    .set instance void SimpleClass::set_Number(int32)
  } // end of property SimpleClass::Number
} // end of class SimpleClass
```

Especialmente:

```
  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
          instance void  .ctor() cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    IL_0006:  nop
    IL_0007:  ret
  } // end of method Program::.ctor
```

O compilador gerou um método chamado `.ctor`. Ele é um **método de instância, não estático tratado de forma especial pelo CLR** e ele sempre chama o construtor da classe ascendente, no caso `Object`.

Mas se tiver um construtor estático, aí ele se chamara `.cctor` e ainda será estático (e obrigatoriamente privado:

```
  .method private hidebysig specialname rtspecialname static 
          void  .cctor() cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ret
  } // end of method Program::.cctor
```

Em um construtor criado pelo programador teria outros códigos aí, e poderia inclusive atribuir valores para membros da classe. Independente disto existe a inicialização dos membros ocorrendo durante a construção (realizada pelo CLR independente e antes do construtor, conforme pode ser observado em [outra pergunta sobre o tema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108516/101).

Note que há construtor nas duas classes. De modo geral uma classe que só terá membros estáticos pode ser declarada como estática e evitar a existência do construtor de instância.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

Porque sua classe ganha também um construtor implícito, apelidado de `ctor`. Ele é criado quando não há construtores definidos pelo programador.

Não sei se você já teve essa ideia de colocar um breakpoint em `SimpleClass sc = new SimpleClass();` e apertar <kbd>F11</kbd>. A próxima linha de execução vai cair aqui:

```
public int Number { get; private set; }
```

Ou seja, independente de você ter um construtor vazio ou não, a classe precisa inicializar a propriedade de uma forma ou de outra.

Nessa inicialização, alguns valores são definidos por padrão quando o programador não os informa. [Aqui você pode ver todos eles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

no c# todo tem 2 tipos de dados os 

**tipos de referencias:referency type** esses tipos recebem valores padrão null,

**tipos de val:value type** ex:int,char,bool.
estes tem um valor padrão, predefinidos, e o do int é 0 

neste caso:    int i; i++; da um erro de compilação que uma forma de prevenção do compilador, mas noutro caso ja estão em run time e ai as propiedades recebem todas os seus valores padrão, por isto não da erro,

outra coisa é que o int e todo **value type** são non nullable type ou seja nunca são nulos.