# Qual é a finalidade de um construtor estático?

Tags: c#, .net, característica-linguagem, construtor

Sempre utilizei construtores da seguinte forma:

```
public MinhaClasse()
{
  //Algo
  ...
}
```

Entretanto descobri que no C# é possível criar um construtor estático da seguinte forma:

```
public class MinhaClasse
{
    public string Propriedade { get; set; }

    static MinhaClasse() 
    {
        //Algo
        ....
    }
}
```

E a classe com o construtor estático é instanciada da mesma forma que uma classe comum:

```
MinhaClasse c = new MinhaClasse();
c.Propriedade = "Hello Stackoverflow";
WriteLine(c.Propriedade);
```

Saída:

> Hello Stackoverflow

---

## Dúvidas

Qual é a finalidade de um construtor estático e quais são as diferenças do construtor estático em comparação com o construtor padrão?

Comment: Existe isso de construtor estático? Nossa, pra mim isso é novo. hehe

Comment: @diegofm tentei no Java mas não funcionou ele diz q é invalido, porem no C# funciona hehe

Comment: por isso que eu desconhecia, é um problema sério a gente ficar fechado a uma linguagem apenas viu. :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506990/what-is-the-use-of-static-constructors

Comment: Tem no Java tb, tem um *link* na minha resposta que fala disto

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não vou entrar em muitos detalhes porque várias informações pertinentes ao assunto já foram respondidas em outras perguntas. Estou imaginando que entende a [diferença entre membros estáticos e membros de instância](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138542/101).

O construtor estático serve para inicializar os membros estáticos da classe (em oposição a inicializar os membros do objeto instanciado). E ele é chamado exclusivamente pelo [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118694/101) em algum momento antes de algum membro estático ser usado, seguindo regras estabelecidas na especificação (se tudo correr bem será chamado apenas uma vez e não há como controlar sua chamada). Só pode existir um construtor sem parâmetro.

Como é comum que os membros já sejam inicializados por conta própria raramente precisamos escrevê-los. Mas pode haver algumas situações que o compilador não consegue avaliar a expressão da inicialização, pode precisar de uma ordem específica de inicialização (um depende do outro), fazer algo extra além da inicialização, então ele pode ser útil.

Sua utilidade é a mesma de um construtor de instância (pode ser vista em perguntas *linkadas* abaixo), nem mais nem menos, só muda os membros que ele pode manipular.

Na verdade o compilador também gera um construtor estático sempre que há alguma inicialização de membros estáticos. A inicialização não pode ocorrer magicamente, qualquer código a ser executado deve estar sempre dentro de um método, no caso o construtor estático.

```
public class Exemplo {
    static int x = 1;
}
```

No fundo será gerado algo assim:

```
public class Exemplo {
    static int x;
    static Exemplo() { x = 1; }
}
```

Código IL gerado para o código da pergunta (note a existência de dois `ctor`, um normal e outro de instância e note o `beforefieldinit` ):

```
.class private auto ansi '<Module>'
{
} // end of class <Module>

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit Program
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig static 
        void Main () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 32 (0x20)
        .maxstack 2
        .locals init (
            [0] class MinhaClasse
        )

        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: newobj instance void MinhaClasse::.ctor() //   <========= note a chamada ao método de instância
        IL_0006: stloc.0
        IL_0007: ldloc.0
        IL_0008: ldstr "Hello Stackoverflow"
        IL_000d: callvirt instance void MinhaClasse::set_Propriedade(string)
        IL_0012: nop
        IL_0013: ldloc.0
        IL_0014: callvirt instance string MinhaClasse::get_Propriedade()
        IL_0019: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        IL_001e: nop
        IL_001f: ret
    } // end of method Program::Main

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x207c
        // Code size 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: nop
        IL_0007: ret
    } // end of method Program::.ctor

} // end of class Program

.class public auto ansi MinhaClasse
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Fields
    .field private string '<Propriedade>k__BackingField'
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableState) = (
        01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    )

    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig specialname 
        instance string get_Propriedade () cil managed 
    {
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2085
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldfld string MinhaClasse::'<Propriedade>k__BackingField'
        IL_0006: ret
    } // end of method MinhaClasse::get_Propriedade

    .method public hidebysig specialname 
        instance void set_Propriedade (
            string 'value'
        ) cil managed 
    {
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        // Method begins at RVA 0x208d
        // Code size 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldarg.1
        IL_0002: stfld string MinhaClasse::'<Propriedade>k__BackingField'
        IL_0007: ret
    } // end of method MinhaClasse::set_Propriedade

    .method private hidebysig specialname rtspecialname static  
        void .cctor () cil managed   //<============== construtor estático aqui
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2096
        // Code size 2 (0x2)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: ret
    } // end of method MinhaClasse::.cctor

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed   //<============== construtor de instância aqui
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x207c
        // Code size 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: nop
        IL_0007: ret
    } // end of method MinhaClasse::.ctor

    // Properties
    .property instance string Propriedade()
    {
        .get instance string MinhaClasse::get_Propriedade()
        .set instance void MinhaClasse::set_Propriedade(string)
    }

} // end of class MinhaClasse
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/StaticConstructor.cs).

## Evite o uso

É recomendando evitar o uso tanto quanto possível principalmente se deseja performance.

É um perigo fazer algo que gere uma exceção em um construtor estático. Quem chamou tem que capturar, certo? Não foi seu código que chamou ele, foi a máquina virtual. Desastre à vista (a classe fica em estado inválido - não as instâncias).

Em versões modernas do C# é possível controlar o momento da inicialização para evitar surpresas.

## Parece o construtor estático, mas não é.

Na verdade no exemplo de uso da pergunta o que está chamando não é o construtor estático, é o construtor de instância sem parâmetros que o compilador gera para você (*default constructor*) para que a classe possa ser instanciada em qualquer situação. O construtor de instância serve para inicializar os membros de instância.

## Diferença entre eles

Basicamente é o que eles manipulam e como são chamados. Mas há pequenas diferenças, como a maneira como pode defini-los, por exemplo.

Mais informações:

- [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101)
- [Diferença entre método e construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104707/101)
- [Como funciona a inicialização de campos em construtores?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111152/101)
- [Blocos estáticos, herança e construtores em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104512/101) (é Java, funciona um pouco diferente em C#, mas dá uma ideia)
- [Artigo do Jon Skeet](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx)
- [Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Comment: Eu ia fazer um comentário extra, mas acho que iria criar confusão: no fundo podemos enxergar o construtor de instância como um método estático que gera uma instância.

Answer (score 8):

Um construtor estático em C# nunca pode ser chamado diretamente através de código (no caso da sua aplicação foi criado um construtor não estático implícito pelo compilador).

O construtor estático é chamado antes da primeira utilização da classe, seja ela uma chamada estática ou através de objeto a esta classe.

A principal finalidade deste tipo de construtor é inicialização de membros estáticos automaticamente, considerando por exemplo que é necessária a chamada de um método específico para inicializar uma propriedade estática desta classe isto poderia ser feito manualmente (chance do programador esquecer de fazê-la e corromper a classe) ou através da invocação do construtor estática pela aplicação automaticamente quando a chamada estática a esta classe for invocada (especificamente antes da chamada).

Complementando ainda, como as outras respostas colocaram:
O construtor estático não pode conter parâmetros e não pode ser invocado manualmente pelo usuário da classe, portanto também não será impactado por modificadores public, protected e private.