# O que é o código IL e onde eu posso encontrar este código?

Tags: c#, .net

Na minha [pergunta a respeito de construtores estáticos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138554/27190) o usuário [Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/Maniero) mostrou como é o código gerado de um construtor estático pelo .NET, este código é chamado de *Código IL* de acordo com a resposta dele.

Veja o código IL da minha pergunta:

```
.class private auto ansi '<Module>'
{
} // end of class <Module>

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit Program
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig static 
        void Main () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 32 (0x20)
        .maxstack 2
        .locals init (
            [0] class MinhaClasse
        )

        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: newobj instance void MinhaClasse::.ctor()
        IL_0006: stloc.0
        IL_0007: ldloc.0
        IL_0008: ldstr "Hello Stackoverflow"
        IL_000d: callvirt instance void MinhaClasse::set_Propriedade(string)
        IL_0012: nop
        IL_0013: ldloc.0
        IL_0014: callvirt instance string MinhaClasse::get_Propriedade()
        IL_0019: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        IL_001e: nop
        IL_001f: ret
    } // end of method Program::Main

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x207c
        // Code size 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: nop
        IL_0007: ret
    } // end of method Program::.ctor

} // end of class Program

.class public auto ansi MinhaClasse
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Fields
    .field private string '<Propriedade>k__BackingField'
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableState) = (
        01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    )

    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig specialname 
        instance string get_Propriedade () cil managed 
    {
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2085
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldfld string MinhaClasse::'<Propriedade>k__BackingField'
        IL_0006: ret
    } // end of method MinhaClasse::get_Propriedade

    .method public hidebysig specialname 
        instance void set_Propriedade (
            string 'value'
        ) cil managed 
    {
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        // Method begins at RVA 0x208d
        // Code size 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldarg.1
        IL_0002: stfld string MinhaClasse::'<Propriedade>k__BackingField'
        IL_0007: ret
    } // end of method MinhaClasse::set_Propriedade

    .method private hidebysig specialname rtspecialname static  
        void .cctor () cil managed   //<============== construtor estático aqui
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2096
        // Code size 2 (0x2)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: ret
    } // end of method MinhaClasse::.cctor

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed   //<============== construtor de instância aqui
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x207c
        // Code size 8 (0x8)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: nop
        IL_0007: ret
    } // end of method MinhaClasse::.ctor

    // Properties
    .property instance string Propriedade()
    {
        .get instance string MinhaClasse::get_Propriedade()
        .set instance void MinhaClasse::set_Propriedade(string)
    }

} // end of class MinhaClasse
```

Que é o código correspondente a classe que usei de exemplo na minha pergunta.

---

## Dúvidas

O que é este *Código IL* e como ver o código IL dos meus softwares que eu desenvolvo no Visual Studio em C#?

Comment: Veja essa pergunta, pode ser útil http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118694/18246

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IL é a Intermediate Language, ou seja, é uma linguagem intermediária gerada pelos compiladores que pretendem rodar em cima do [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101) e conformar com a [CLI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118707/101). Este código é uma espécie de linguagem Assembly. O código roda em uma plataforma que é uma máquina virtual que simula um processador que executará o *bytecode* gerado por esse Assembly. O nome oficial é [Common Intermediate Language, ou CIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language), e alguns gostam de chamar de MSIL por ter sido criado pela Microsoft.

Até seria possível que essa máquina virtual execute esse *bytecode*, mas o que ocorre de fato é que ele seja convertido para código nativo do processador real sendo usado antes de ser usado. Essa conversão pode ocorrer antes de executar, na inicialização da aplicação, antecipadamente na instalação, ou mais recentemente pode até mesmo ser gerado originalmente assim no processo de criação da aplicação.

[A especificação de tudo isso pode ser baixada](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/mt639507?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

O próprio .NET possui uma descompilador chamado [Ildasm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). O Mono possui o [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/). É possível obter o código IL até mesmo no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) ou [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/). Existem diversos outros grátis e pagos, alguns bons, outros nem tanto. Alguns exemplos:

- [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)
- [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx)
- [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)
- [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)
- [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)
- [Msiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=segrived.Msiler) (extensão para o Visual Studio)
- [.NET CodeReflect](http://www.devextras.com/decompiler/)
- [Assembly Analyzer](http://asmanalyzer.codeplex.com/)
- [IL.view](https://github.com/DenisVuyka/IL.View)
- [Reflexil](http://reflexil.net/)
- [.NET IL Editor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dile/)
- [Dis#](http://www.netdecompiler.com/)
- [Spices .NET Decompiler](http://www.9rays.net/Category/54-spicesnet-decompiler.aspx)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Nossa, bigown... até tento competir, mas você é uma máquina de bolar respostas. Bom trabalho!

Comment: Ouvi dizer que um código já escrito em IL é muito mais rapido do que um código em C#. Sendo assim, é vantajoso converter um código para o IL? Igual quando a gente diminui códigos CSSs e JSs para ganhar mais rapidez.

Comment: Isso em geral não é verdade, claro que existem padrões que seja possível escrever algo que execute mais rápido com enorme esforço. Nem em Assembly isso já não costuma ser mais verdade em muitas situações, imagine no IL que é de nível mais alto.

Answer (score 7):

O código IL ao qual o Maniero se refere é o Common Intermediate Language, linguagem intermediária equivalente ao *assembly* em linguagens de programação compiladas.

Como o C# é uma linguagem interpretada o compilador da Microsoft gera o código intermediário de tal forma que para a máquina virtual que o executa ele seja tão otimizado quanto um código binário (não é verdade sempre, mas esta é a ideia).

O código IL pode ser obtido executando uma espécie de "disassembler" para `exes` compilados em .NET, como por exemplo o [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/).