# Resgatar código de um programa executável?

Tags: c#, .net, descompilação, .exe

Criei um programa para apresentar no colégio, mas devido a problemas no meu HD, eu perdi o código dele e apenas tenho o executável que eu criei para apresentá-lo. Infelizmente, também preciso do código e necessito saber se é possível resgatar sem ter que criar todo programa novamente.

Estou usando o Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Creio que seja possivel sim.Espero que isso lhe ajude.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/pt-BR/c5a54e85-f6a9-4bcb-bbc9-386eb18f1341/como-descompilar-um-exe?forum=vsvbasicpt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se for algo simples é fácil e a melhor coisa é fazer de novo. Se é algo complexo não obterá um bom resultado descompilando o código. Em qualquer caso o resultado melhor é fazer de novo, aproveitar para aprender mais um pouco e tomar mais cuidado na próxima vez. A descompilação não gera um bom resultado para que possa ser trabalhado adequadamente.

Mas se quiser insistir tem uma [pergunta que mostra algumas opções para ver o código IL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138577/101) e que também geram o código em C#. Alguns funcionam melhor que outros.

Se por acaso estiver pensando em fazer isso em códigos de terceiros, pense duas vezes, pode estar cometendo alguma ilegalidade.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

Se tu tens a DLL ou o EXE, dá pra o usar o gratuito Jet Brains DotPeek 
https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Um colega precisou usar e conseguiu recriar o código. Só não vem os comentários.
E pode dar mais trabalho se você fez Obfuscation no seu código.