# Dúvida com Decompilando projeto VB.NET

Tags: java, c#, vb.net

Uma classe compilada em J# ou vb.net após está em uma DLL, existe algum programa que possa decompilar passando um código que esta em vb.net para C# ou J# para c#?

Comment: Explique melhor o que deseja, provavelmente já foi respondido em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138577/101

Comment: JustDecompile : http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx

Comment: uma pessoa na empresa falou que era possível pegar uma DLL em vb.net decompilar  e após isso seria possível transformar este código em C#, na verdade ele salvaria o código em C#, então eu fiquei sem saber se isso é possível.