# Any CPU ou x64?

Tags: visual-studio, desempenho, compilação, x64, jit

Procurei sobre compilação em Any CPU e x64, mas não achei nada em relação a performance e tamanho de arquivos. Existe diferença entre esses dois nesta questão quando a maquina é x64?

Website usando C# em VS 2017, MVC 3, .NET Framework 4.7

Comment: Se tentar deixar a pergunta um pouco mais clara do que deseja, se é C#, etc. pode dar uma boa pergunta.

Comment: nao eh sobre o c#, eh sobre compilar mesmo, eh a diferenca entre o produto final da compilação em anycpu e x64 quando vc roda isso em uma maquina x64. os arquivos finais tem tamanhos diferentes? a performance do software eh a mesma?

Comment: Compilar onde? Usando o que? AnyCPU tem a ver com C#. .NET Framework, Core ou Native?

Comment: Vs2017, codigo escrito em c# MVC 3 .NET Framework 4.7 sorry, my bad

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No .NET Framework não faz diferença em termos de tamanho de executável porque o código gerado é um [CIL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138577/101) e não um código nativo, o que vai é um *bytecode* que na execução gerará um código nativo através do [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101).

O que muda quando escolhe uma CPU ou deixar para qualquer uma é onde o código poderá rodar, é para criar as dependências certas.

Se tiver alguma dependência nativa pode fazer diferença.

Se escolher x64 não poderá rodar em uma máquina x86 e se escolher x86 rodará em modo de compatibilidade no x64.

Se escolher Any CPU o *runtime* gerará o código nativo de acordo com a arquitetura que está executando.

Assemblies do .NET não podem misturar arquiteturas, então se escolher uma delas, só poderá rodar junto com *assemblies* da mesma arquitetura.

O código nativo x64 será um pouco maior porque todo endereçamento ocupará 8 bytes em vez de 4 bytes que é o tamanho do x86. Há outras diferenças de instruções que pode fazer o código nativo na memória ficar maior ou menor.

De forma geral o x64 roda mais rápido, mas nem sempre. Mas não precisa escolher, deixe o Any CPU.

Em alguns casos escolher o x86 pode dar alguma vantagem, só testando para saber.

O [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101) escolhe a melhor forma quando está no Any CPU, então quase sempre é a melhor escolha. Em geral só precisa escolher a arquitetura se for rodar junto um código não gerenciado para uma delas especificamente.

[Artigo com mais detalhes](https://web.archive.org/web/20200117020919/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-45-and-visual-studio-11/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: show de bola, muito obrigado, matou todas as duvidas :)