# Como a Unity utiliza C# no Android?

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, clr

Recentemente comecei a me interessar por desenvolvimento de games (inicialmente para a plataforma Android) e foi por isso que conheci a *engine* Unity. Eu nunca programei em Java, linguagem nativa do Android. Entretanto conheço a linguagem C#.

Ao ler mais sobre a mencionada *engine*, verifiquei que é possível apenas utilizar duas linguagens "algo derivado do Javascript" e C#. Baseado nisso, algumas dúvidas me surgiram:

- Isso significa que é possível gerar versões de *bytecodes* do C# para CLR e JVM?
- Achei que só fosse possível fazer isso através do Xamarim.
- Como fica a questão do SDK e o acesso as APIs do sistema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Isso significa que é possível gerar versões de bytecodes do C# para CLR e JVM? Achei que só fosse possível fazer isso através do Xamarim.

O sistema de *scripting* do Unity é uma implementação que usa o Mono em sua base, assim como o Xamarin também o utiliza. No fundo é o Mono que faz tudo do [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101), o Xamarin e o Unity são camadas em cima que tem funcionalidade específica para interagir com o sistema operacional, sendo o Unity de forma mais específica para jogos.

Hoje o Unity tem uma versão própria do *runtime* e o código é convertido para C++ através do [IL2CPP](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/IL2CPP.html). O Unity como plataforma é escrito quase todo em C++. Na verdade, parece que anos depois usa o [.NET padrão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/568799/101), pelo menos em boa parte.

É gerado um [CIL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138577/101) normal que depois é convertido. Nem tente modificar esse código em C++ que não foi feito para consumo humano.

> Como fica a questão do SDK e o acesso as APIs do sistema?

De forma geral é problema do Unity fazer isto e expor apenas a API dele para você usar. Ele pode expor de uma forma idêntica ao do Android, ou pode expor mais no estilo do C#, ou pode fazer algo híbrido. Não sei qual foi o caminho deles. O importante é saber usar a API do Unity.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu sou leigo, mas uma coisa que não consigo compreender é o que levou a Unity a adotar o C#. Quando o assunto é desenvolvimento de games, buscamos sempre desempenho. Com uma linguagem dependente de uma VM, já temos aí um gargalo. Com uma linguagem não nativa, teremos dois. Mas, não entendo porque não adotaram o Java, uma linguagem com mais suporte e mais madura (na minha opinião) e pelo menos no Android teríamos uma barreira a menos.

Comment: Você está correto. Unity não roda só no Android, inicialmente não rodava no Android. Java não roda em um monte de plataforma que interessavam a eles e C# rodava (ao contrário da crença popular). Talvez eles gostassem mais do C#, o que é algo fácil de acontecer. Saber mexer e gostar é um critério muito mais adotado e mais válido na maioria dos casos onde uma ferramenta não seja claramente melhor que outra para uma tarefa.

Comment: Se eu desassemblar um .apk feito com Xamarin terei um codigo CIL (e o Mono) ao invés de um arquivo gerado pelo Java? As ferramentas de ofuscação voltadas para o .net funcionam normalmente e com a mesma eficácia?

Comment: Mais ou menos, não sei se essas ferramentas não causam problema com o Mono e não sei se o Unity não muda um pouco o Mono. E o `.apk` não tem só o CIL. Não conheço detalhes, mas acredito que tenha todo o Mono ali, e uma pá de coisas envolta dele, além de outras coisas específicas do Android.

Comment: Hum.... eu não tenho absoluta certeza, mas suspeito fortemente de que a Unity utilize o Mono só pra validar sintaxe e tals (isto é, C# é somente a linguagem escolhida pra facilitar a implementação dos scripts), e que gere o código Java pra produzir o APK nativo. Mais informações aqui: https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/android-BuildProcess.html (é a documentação da versão anterior, mas não deve ter mudado esse processo).

Comment: @LuizVieira acho que agora está ok, hoje está diferente do que eu conhecia, e eu simplifiquei um pouco o que acabou ficando errado. Pelo que pesquisei é isso aí.

Comment: Bacana. Ficou ótima a edição. :) Se eu pudesse dava +1 +1. rs