# Qual o conceito de máquina virtual? Quais são os pontos positivos e negativos?

Tags: característica-linguagem, máquina-virtual

Gostaria de um comprativo de uma linguagem que usa máquina virtual e uma que não utiliza.

Comment: A [resposta do Manieiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/332794/129) traduz bem o que é uma maquina virtual. Hoje em dia, fala-se muito sobre containers, algo que vale a pena você pesquisar.
Eu costumo resumir e VM no seguinte. Se você precisa de um laboratorio para fazer alguns experimentos, uma VM é uma execelente escolha. Agora por exemplo, se voce precisa usar no mesmo computador um Windows e Linux, utilizar um VM para essa finalidade não seria interessante, por questões de performance. Um dual boot nesse segundo caso seria mais eficiente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vou responder com o viés de VM de aplicação e ignorar outros tipos.

Máquina virtual é uma simulação de uma máquina real através de um software. Portanto é criado um software que executará na máquina real (tecnicamente poderia rodar em cima de outra máquina virtual, mas faz pouco sentido) como uma aplicação normal, e sua função é reproduzir as características de uma máquina real para rodar um código de outra aplicação. Em alguns casos é só um passo intermediário.

A máquina virtual costuma ter uma [linguagem Assembly própria](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138577/101) assim como um processador tem, e as suas aplicações são escritas, em última análise, nesta linguagem, mas claro que a origem do código pode ser em outras linguagens. Normalmente o código fonte é compilado para este Assembly antes ou durante a execução.

Algumas máquinas interpretam esse Assembly e rodam em uma laço decidindo o que executar em um enorme `switch` com cada instrução. Outras usam um [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) que transformam este Assembly no Assembly do processador físico onde está rodando (que virará código de máquina) ou até direto o código de máquina dele, o mais comum.

É possível em alguns casos ter uma máquina virtual que ocorre uma interpretação onde toda tradução ocorre conforme vai executando. Ou até pode ter alguma VM que não tenha esse processo todo e sirva só para controle maior de acesso à aplicação, então ela pode usar o próprio Assembly do processador. Mas são implementações bem incomuns.

## Vantagens

- A maior vantagem é a independência de plataforma física. Em geral ela abstrai tudo e se torna a plataforma onde você programa. É problema dela como fazer aquilo rodar bem na plataforma física e a sua como programar é só fazer o seu código de acordo com a VM sem se preocupar se está rodando em x86, x64, ARM, Windows, Linux, iOS, Android, etc. Isto pode incluir uma facilidade maior por ter APIs mais simples de usar.
- Outra grande vantagem é ter um controle sobre a execução podendo limitar o que a aplicação consegue acessar da plataforma real tais como: ter a memória gerenciada, ter outros controles, ou ter o código assinado. Dá mais segurança e robustez e pode rodar até mesmo como parte de outras aplicações. E nesse ambiente controlado pode ser mais fácil rodar certas ferramentas de controle, de depuração, de flexibilização e de análise. Nem sempre isso é verdade, depende de implementação.
- Em alguns casos é possível dar mais performance por transformar na plataforma mais específica, ou adaptar o código, ou dar um viés mais específico. Mas na prática isso não acaba acontecendo quando comparado com alternativas avançadas de aplicações que rodam 100% nativas. Só vale para alguns tipos.

Em geral as vantagens dadas podem ser obtidas em aplicações nativas, apenas não da mesma forma, com compromissos um pouco diferentes. Nos dois casos é preciso abrir mão de algumas coisas, mas dá para ter facilidade, performance, segurança e capacidade de rodar várias plataformas.

## Desvantagens

- Obviamente é um custo adicional para alguém desenvolver e manter uma VM, sempre uma fonte nova de problemas e depende de uma plataforma menos consagrada (embora isto tende mudar ao longo do tempo em casos de VMs que fazem muito sucesso).
- É uma plataforma nova para aprender. Pode compensar ou não.
- É comum ela ter um custo extra porque é uma aplicação que vai junto ou precisa estar previamente instalada para rodar sua aplicação.
- Há um custo de execução de alguma forma, em alguns casos bem caro. Mas algumas podem eliminar isso antes.

Também existe uma série e vantagens e desvantagens específicas de alguma VM ou de necessidade pontual.

## O que muda para a linguagem de programação

Para a linguagem em si pouco ou nada, a menos que sua especificação determine algo específico em relação a isso, incluindo ter algum requisito que exija que só possa ser feito em uma VM ou que seja proibido usá-la.

Salvo o dito acima, implementações de linguagens podem ser feitas tanto para rodar em uma VM ou não. Cada uma terá suas vantagens e desvantagens desde que atenda a especificação da linguagem.

## Exemplos de VMs conhecidas:

- [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) (várias implementações e variações como a [Dalvik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_virtual_machine))
- [CLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) (algumas implementações do .NET e Mono)
- [LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) (não costuma ir junto com a sua aplicação)
- [Parrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parrot_virtual_machine) (tentativa de universalizar VMs para linguagens dinâmicas)
- WebAssembly, Flash e JS (diversas que rodam em *browsers* e outras formas usando plataforma web)
- SQL (quase todos DBs usam VM, [exemplo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite))
- [BEAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEAM_(Erlang_virtual_machine)) (Erlang, Elixir e outras)
- [NekoVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NekoVM) (bem pouco usada)
- [HHVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HHVM) - (Hack e PHP do Facebook)
- [p-code machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-code_machine) (implementação inicial de Pascal)
- [Valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) (usado para controle de ambiente)

Em essência todas as linguagens chamadas dinâmicas rodam em uma VM. Não é obrigatório o seu uso, mas se o dinamismo for muito importante é muito mais fácil assim. Isto vale para JS, PHP, Python, Ruby, Perl, Lua, Smalltalk, VB (clássico) e vários BASICs, as linguagens xBase, várias implementações de LISP, etc.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).