# Quem faz os cálculos aritméticos é o compilador, algum outro componente, ou varia conforme a linguagem?

Tags: assembly, ciência-da-computação, arquitetura-computadores

Para se fazer uma função de soma em C:

```c
void SOMA(float a, int b)
{
   float result;
   result = a+b;
   printf("A soma de %6.3f com %d é %6.3f\n", a,b,result);
}
```

Em Python:

```py
def soma(a,b):
    return a+b
```

E em diversas linguagens, é semelhante.

Mas como de fato essa conta é feita? Quem é o responsável pelo cálculo quando digitamos `1 + 1`? O compilador? Depende da linguagem? Seria tipo um ponteiro que vai se incrementando?

E multiplicação? É um loop incrementando algum tipo de ponteiro?
É tudo convertido para binário?

Comment: OBS: Nao sei quais tags utilizar

Comment: Editei para focar nas operações aritméticas, que parece ser o cerne da pergunta. Se não for esse o caso, basta revertê-la.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Atenção:** Se está buscando uma resposta focando apenas na camada *high-level* da coisa, pule para a segunda parte dessa resposta. Se você quer realmente saber quem faz as operações de soma, subtração e outras, continue lendo a resposta partir daqui.

---

De forma bem simples, podemos dizer que quem faz os cálculos é o processador. No entanto, o processador é na verdade um conjunto de componentes como o PC, ALU, UC, registradores e outros, que dá vida ao computador. Então, aqui vai uma explicação mais detalhada sobre o assunto.

Sendo mais específico, quem realiza os cálculos é um componente do processador chamado [ALU (Arithmetic Logic Unit)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidade_l%C3%B3gica_e_aritm%C3%A9tica), que é responsável por realizar todas operações matemáticas do processador. Porém, é possível ir ainda mais a fundo. Dentro da ALU nós temos vários subcircuitos e, um deles, é o [*adder*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuito_aritm%C3%A9tico#Circuito_Somador). Esse subcircuito, como o nome já diz, é responsável por fazer a soma de dois binários de N bits.

Essa soma é feita utilizando as [portas lógicas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porta_l%C3%B3gica#:%7E:text=Portas%20ou%20circuitos%20l%C3%B3gicos%20s%C3%A3o,da%20fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20implementada%20no%20circuito.&text=As%20situa%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20%22Verdade%22%20e%20%22,origem%20do%20nome%20destas%20portas.) XOR e AND, retornando os seguintes valores:

| Bit 1 | Bit 2 | Result (porta XOR) | Carry (porta AND) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Esse `carry` é o nosso famoso *"vai um"*. Se somarmos dois bits **1**, teremos o resultado dois em decimal, e em binário **10**. Nesse caso, o `result` seria **0** e o `carry` (vai um) seria o **1**. É importante saber disso pois, diferentemente do que muitos pensam, não é possível realizar somas "infinitas" com computadores. Isso porque, computadores possuem uma limitação física. Literalmente!

E aqui vai a resposta final, que explodiu minha mente quando eu descobri, sobre como as somas são realizadas. Por fios, individualmente!

Cada bit dos binários é somado individualmente, utilizando aquela tabela, através de um somador de bits, e o resultado final da soma é obtido a partir dessas N somas. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
binario_1 = 01110
binario_2 = 00101

0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0      <-- Vai um (carry)
--+---+---+---+---     
0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0      <-- Binário 1
0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1      <-- Binário 2
--+---+---+---+---
1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1      <-- Resultado
```

Cada coluna acima representa um somador de bit. E cada bit é literalmente um fio. Sendo assim, podemos ter um circuito que recebe, por exemplo, dois valores binários de 8 fios e retorna um valor binário de 8 fios. Em outras palavras, se seu computador é 64 bits, significa que para cada valor, existem 64 fios passando pelos componentes, e a soma de dois binários exigem 64 somadores de bits. Já pensou em somar dois valores com 64 dígitos? Loucura né?

Mas aqui vai uma pergunta: e se ultrapassar? E se a soma for `11111111 + 11111111`? Não é possível adicionar fios dinamicamente ao computador, sempre que necessário. Então o que acontece quando isso ocorre? Simples! **ERROR!!** Assim como o somador de bits possui uma saída para o `carry`, o somador de binários também possui. E essa saída é chamada de "indicador de overflow".

Lembra alguma coisa? Exatamente! É essa a saída responsável por gerar um **OverflowError** bem grande e vermelho na sua tela. Como não seria possível adicionar aquele último bit ao resultado, por uma limitação física, o resultado seria incorreto, e você não quer ter valores incorretos certo?

Por isso, esse erro, apesar de chato, é bem importante que ocorra. E para fins de curiosidade, em uma arquitetura 64 bits, o resultado da soma dos valores, em decimal, deve ser maior ou igual à 2<sup>64</sup> ou `18_446_744_073_709_551_616`, para que um *overflow* ocorra.

---

E só para complementar, subtrações ocorrem da mesma forma que as somas. Isso porque a subtração no computador é na verdade uma soma. É... bem estranho, não?

O que ocorre é uma transformação do valor binário, em sua representação, para que a soma seja possível. Existem [três tipos de representação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_n%C3%BAmeros_com_sinal): Complemento de 1, Complemento de 2 e S-M.

Atualmente, os computadores utilizam a representação de Complemento de 2, para evitar certas anomalias que ocorrem nas outras representações. Essa representação funciona da seguinte forma:

- Valor positivo: O binário continua o mesmo.
- Valor negativo: Inverte os bits do binário e soma 1 ao valor.

Ou seja, nessa representação, o valor `5` é `0101`, e o valor `-5` é `1010 + 1 = 1011`. Na matemática, o que é uma subtração `X - Y`? É basicamente a soma `X + (-Y)`.

É exatamente esse o conceito utilizado pelo computador na hora do cálculo. Ele negativa o valor e soma com o outro. Sendo assim, a subtração `5 - 10` seria feita da seguinte forma:

```
00101 - 01010  =>  00101 + (10101 + 1)  =>  00101 + 10110 = 11011
```

O resultado dessa operação é `-5` em Complemento de 2. Você pode conferir isso transformando o valor para positivo, seguindo aqueles mesmos passos de inverter os bits e somar 1 ao binário.

Dessa forma, não é necessário criar um circuito novo para que o computador realize operações de subtração. Ele pode simplesmente reutilizar o circuito de soma, negativando o valor da direita e/ou o valor da esquerda. E vale ressaltar que o mesmo ocorre para as outras representações. O que muda são suas transformações de valores, de positivo para negativo.

Detalhe: Para saber se um valor é positivo ou negativo, em qualquer representação, até mesmo no padrão [IEEE-754](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/493487/157404), basta olhar o primeiro bit (MSB). Se for **0** é positivo, se for **1** é negativo.

---

Saindo do *hardware* e voltando para o nosso confortável *high-level* (ou nem tanto assim), agora que já entendemos a origem, vamos falar das linguagens de programação.

Nesse exemplo da sua pergunta, o que nós temos não é exatamente uma "operação" sendo feita, mas sim uma instrução. E pode parecer extremamente óbvio isso, mas acho que precisava ser dito.

Como já vimos, temos uma máquina pronta para uso, com todas as ferramentas para realizar cálculos disponíveis. Mas e aí? Como manipulá-la? Simples! Usamos uma linguagem de programação como JS, C#, Java, Rust, Python, etc. Né!? Éééééé... mais ou menos.

De fato, através dessas linguagens, conseguimos criar instruções e assim construir programas a serem executados. Mas não são elas que fazem isso.

Toda CPU é construída seguindo uma arquitetura. Entenda a CPU como um "programa", só que ao invés de ter código, ele possui circuitos. Ela é preparada para utilizar seus componentes através de instruções em um X formato.

Um exemplo legal que posso dar foi meu trabalho da faculdade. O professor pediu para criar uma arquitetura em que a CPU trabalhasse com instruções no formato `<4 bits operação><2 bits endereço_1><2 bits endereço_2>` e deu uma lista de operações a serem implementadas na CPU.

Por exemplo:

| Operação | Representação binária |
| --- | --- |
| Soma | 0100 |
| Subtração | 0101 |
| Multiplicação | 0110 |
| Divisão | 0111 |

Isso significa que se o processador recebesse a instrução `01101011`, ele deveria multiplicar os valores dos registradores nos endereços `10` e `11`.

A propósito, o "*parse*" das instruções é feita no componente [UC (Control Unit)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidade_de_controle), caso tenha interesse em saber quem interpreta a instrução binária.

Como você deve ter notado, a partir daí conseguimos criar uma sequência de instruções binárias a serem executadas pela CPU. E esse é o mais *low-level* que você pode chegar em programação.

As outras linguagens, que utilizamos diariamente, seja linguagem *low-level* ou *high-level* são apenas formas de criar instruções fáceis de escrever, ler e entender, para que depois possam ser traduzidas para aquele tipo de instrução, chamado linguagem de máquina ou código binário, através de um compilador.

E vale ressaltar que compiladores não necessariamente convertem o código para linguagem de máquina. Os compiladores, como do C# ou Java por exemplo, podem compilar o código primeiro para uma linguagem, que não a de máquina, para a ser interpretada por um software, que irá compilar as instruções em tempo de execução.

Comment: Por isso que tá sumido, ta fazendo faculdade. Sucesso!!!

Comment: Vlw @AugustoVasques!!

Answer (score 8):

Respondendo ao que foi perguntado:

Quem faz o cálculo é o processador, só ele faz qualquer manipulação de dados na máquina, o resto do hardware serve para para armazenar dados e para fazer a entrada e saída dos dados. Ver [O que é a arquitetura de Von Neumann?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189180/101).

Sempre um software instrui o que o processador deve fazer. Ver [Como um computador entende o código binário?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142289/101).

Não é bem cada linguagem que faz isso do jeito que quiser, é a [implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101) da linguagem que faz. Ver [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101).

Em C o mais comum é que o compilador transforme seu texto em código nativo binário embarcado em um arquivo executável. Em Python o mais comum é que exista uma interpretação que mandará para o processador o que fazer. Ver [Qual a diferença entre linguagem compilada para linguagem interpretada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77070/101).

De qualquer forma o processador recebe a instrução que você quer fazer a soma de dois valores e antes há instrução para os valores virem da memória para processador, e depois do cálculo deve colocar o resultado na memória. A forma exata depende da linguagem e sua implementação, mas no fim mais ou menos as mesmas instruções serão executadas (por otimização pode ser um pouco diferente).

Não tem nada de *loop*, muito menos de ponteiro, a não ser que seja algo mais complexo do que isso. Em linguagens interpretadas existe um *loop* de interpretação, mas é outra coisa, nada relacionado com a soma. Ver [Qual o conceito de máquina virtual? Quais são os pontos positivos e negativos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/332789/101).

Ver [Como é feito um compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101).

Pode ser útil ver outros conceitos em *links* disponíveis em [Como exatamente um programa é executado pelo navegador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/536507/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Quem faz a operação aritmética da soma em si é o processador, instruído pelo programa sendo executado pelo sistema operacional da máquina ou, em outras ocasiões, pelo próprio software do sistema operacional.

Basicamente os dois operandos da adição são colocados em registradores (pequenas porções isoladas de memória tipicamente volátil) e é chamada uma instrução da unidade lógico-aritmética (componente do processador comandado pela unidade de controle) que efetua a soma dos conteúdos desses dois registradores por meio de um encadeamento de [full adders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)).

Vendo o conceito teórico (na prática ocorrem otimizações no circuito), um *full adder* é um circuito que faz somente a parte de somar um bit com outro bit e mais um "vai um" do *full adder* anterior, produzir um bit de resultado e fazer o próximo "vai um", que é passar o excedente da soma binária/booleana para o próximo *full adder*. A operação de soma completa é portanto resultado de uma combinação de *full adders* (cujo resultado acaba indo para um registrador).

*Full adders* podem ser compostos por *half-adders*, que são um componente mais simples ainda (em termos de circuitos lógicos e da operação que eles fazem - somar dois bits e produzir um bit de resultado e um de um eventual "vai um").

Multiplicações por sua vez podem ser feitas através da combinação de circuitos de soma. A abstração do circuito de soma pode ser aproveitada para implementar a operação de multiplicação.

Essas operações são "cravadas" no hardware, não há ponteiros envolvidos nesse momento da execução. O processador só entende de processar o conteúdo de registradores, mover conteúdo dos registradores para a memória, e vice-versa. Nos passos da operação de adição proposta acima em particular não há envolvimento direto de ponteiros.

No meu parco entendimento o processador é capaz de executar instruções que recebem uma porção de informação que seja o endereço na memória de outra porção de informação (portanto um ponteiro ou indireção; mas não exatamente um ponteiro do C, e sim um de baixo nível, embora funcionem de maneira parecida), e assim é bem provável que o conteúdo dos registradores para a operação de adição possa vir da memória por meio desse mecanismo, mas isso é anterior à chamada à instrução de adição em si.

Há o registrador PC (*Program Counter*) que é o contador de próxima instrução na memória a ser executada, mas para uma adição por exemplo ele só está envolvido na sequência de chamar a instrução que carrega o dado do primeiro registrador, depois a que carrega o dado do segundo, e finalmente chamar a operação de adição desses registradores.

Existe uma variedade de operações de adição implementadas pelo processador, a sequência de passos exata que é chamada pode variar de um código em execução para outro.