# Por que está dizendo que esse objeto é nulo?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, nullpointerexception

```
papelX.moderador = abc.Id;
papelX.participantes.Add(abc);
```

Estou encontrando um `NullReferenceException` nesse código acima. 
Eu estou criando um objeto `papelX` e vou usar algumas propriedades do objeto `abc`.

O Visual Studio está dizendo que na linha de baixo o objeto `abc` é nulo.
Não estou entendendo, pois nessa primeira linha, como vocês podem ver, a propriedade `Id` de `abc` foi devidamente copiada para `papelX.moderador`. Não teve nenhum problema.

Inclusive botando o mouse encima de `abc` percebo que várias propriedades dele estão devidamente preenchidas. Não é nulo. Por que isso está acontecendo?

Comment: Então deve ser mágica. Ou o problema não é bem este. Tem bem pouca informação para podermos ajudar. Se conseguir colocar coisas mais relevantes, aí dá pra ajudar. Não vi o erro exato, se a linha é esta mesma, se há alguma outra coisa que possa estar interferindo. Pode ser que o `participantes` seja nulo e esteja interpretando o erro de forma equivocada. Até poque mesmo que o `abc` seja nulo é provável que isto não seja problema, é possível adicionar nulos para coleções de dados. Eu quase coloquei isto como resposta, já que é só que o que dá p/ responder agora.

Comment: Olá @bigown, obrigado por tentar ajudar. É minha primeira pergunta aqui então não sei muito bem como redigir.
O `participantes` é nulo sim. Ele é um objeto `List<Usuario>`, então espera receber exatamente o tipo do `abc`.
Mas ele começa sem nada pois eu acabei de criar esse objeto `papelX` algumas linhas acimas e estou populando os campos. O Abc seria o primeiro participante, no caso.
Estou fazendo alguma coisa equivocada?

Comment: Antes de `papelX.participantes.Add(abc);` tente colocar `papelX.participantes = new List<Participantes>();`. Note que em `List<Participantes>()`, Participantes é o Model que irá compor a lista.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la agora? Veja o [tour] para entender como funciona. Ajudaria muito indicar para todo mundo que a solução foi útil e satisfatória para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 5):

O erro é justamente porque o membro `participantes` do objeto `papelX` está nulo. Você não pode tentar adicionar alguma coisa em **nada**. Antes é preciso inicializar esse membro, provavelmente com um `new List<Usuario>()`, assim passa ter uma lista vazia ali, aí pode adicionar.

Em condições normais isso já deveria ser feito na [propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108516/101), campo ou [construtor da classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) (preferencialmente nessa ordem), assim o objeto não fica em estado inválido nunca.

Realmente não parece que o `abc` seja nulo. E um nulo poderia ser adicionado a esse `List` sem gerar erro. Se a intenção é não aceitar nulos, o código deveria considerar isso, possivelmente na implementação na propriedade `participantes`. Se é que é uma propriedade (provavelmente deveria ser e deveria seguir o [padrão de nomenclatura do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101) usando maiúsculo).

Eu ajudaria mais se a pergunta tivesse mais informações, como o código, por exemplo.

Comment: Tentei ser sucinto mas vou explicar um pouco melhor: Eu tenho duas classes (entidades) no meu projeto: `Papel` e `Usuario`.
Papel possui essa propriedade `participantes` que nada mais é do que uma lista dos usuários que participaram (  `List<Usuario>` ).
No código a seguir, eu instancio o `Usuario abc`, encho ele com as informações vindas do Javascript, depois instancio o `Papel papelx` e vou preenchendo as propriedades:

Comment: `JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Usuario abc = new Usuario(); 
             abc = js.Deserialize<Usuario>(UsuarioLogado);

            using (Contexto db = new Contexto())
            {
                Papel papelX = new Papel();
                papelX.preenxido = false;
                papelX.moderador = abc.Id;
                papelX.participantes.Add(abc);
            }
`
Devo também instanciar a Lista de Usuario? Onde? Obrigado @bigown

Comment: @RiqueCardoso tem que instanciar, conforme eu já coloquei na resposta. Onde? Não sei, se tivesse colocado na pergunta o seu código eu saberia. Ainda dá para editar lá e colocar. O problema parece estar na classe `Papel`, como já disse ela parece estar mal estruturada.