# Inicializar campos privados na declaração ou no construtor?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, modelagem, construtor

Estou modelando uma classe que possui uma lista privada e uma dependência interna a outro objeto:

```
public class Teste
{
    private IList<string> Textos;
    private Teste2 Teste2;
}
```

Posso inicializá-los na declaração:

```
private IList<string> Textos = new List<string>();
private Teste2= new Teste2();
```

Ou via construtor:

```
public Teste()
{
    Textos = new List<string>();
    Teste2 = new Teste2();
}
```

Qual das duas abordagens é recomendável? É apenas uma questão de estilo de codificação ou alguma delas fere algum princípio da orientação a objeto?

Comment: Não sei se no c# faz diferença, mas em java é a mesma coisa. Se não me engano, mesmo iniciando na declaração, o compilador inicia dentro do construtor padrão. Referencia: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1994232/5524514

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Na verdade, não tem como o campo ser inicializado sozinho, precisa de um código para fazer isso. E códigos só podem ser colocados em métodos. Se é um campo que está sendo inicializado um método na construção precisa ser executado fazendo a inicialização. Então a inicialização no campo é uma ilusão, na verdade ela é jogada no construtor mesmo que você não veja assim. Então dá na mesma.

[Veja como é a mesma coisa](https://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:%3Eilr/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsB0BhA9gG31QGNkxcIRMBxVCVAJzGIG4BYAKE4AdgAjfMxjF8AQxAgYAFVQpUMAN6cYKmNyYA3UWhgBJADJgUAHhRNoAPmmoAHslySAvDHoB3GIZNnIUCwAoASnYOAF9OHn5BYmExCWs5ACZFZVV1MC0dAyNkU2RzX2s7B2CASF4BIRlEwOSOVRgSmSKnF1R3TxzvS0Dg+rDQoA===).

Com inicialização no campo:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
    instance void .ctor () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 18 (0x12)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0              // Load argument 0 onto the stack
    IL_0001: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string>::.ctor() // Allocate an uninitialized object or value type and call ctor
    IL_0006: stfld class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<string> Teste::Textos // Replace the value of field of the object obj with value
    IL_000b: ldarg.0              // Load argument 0 onto the stack
    IL_000c: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor() // Call method indicated on the stack with arguments
    IL_0011: ret                  // Return from method, possibly with a value
} // end of method Teste::.ctor
```

Com inicialização no construtor:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
    instance void .ctor () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2063
    // Code size 18 (0x12)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0              // Load argument 0 onto the stack
    IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor() // Call method indicated on the stack with arguments
    IL_0006: ldarg.0              // Load argument 0 onto the stack
    IL_0007: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string>::.ctor() // Allocate an uninitialized object or value type and call ctor
    IL_000c: stfld class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<string> Teste2::Textos // Replace the value of field of the object obj with value
    IL_0011: ret                  // Return from method, possibly with a value
} // end of method Teste2::.ctor
```

Perceba que o compilador sempre cria um construtor mesmo que você não o declare. E ele coloca a chamada do construtor da classe base dentro do construtor. Ele faz isto o mais cedo possível, **dentro do construtor**. No caso de ter campos com inicializadores isso é colocado **dentro do construtor** antes da chamada do construtor base.

É importante notar que provavelmente o construtor de `Object` desaparecerá já que ele é vazio e o [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) deve eliminá-lo.

Pode ver mais sobre isso em [Nova funcionalidade do C# 6 "Auto-property initializers" é apenas um facilitador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108516/101).

Entenda [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) e porque deve usá-lo ou não.

Eu tendo a evitar o construtor sempre que possível. Tem que usar o que mais faz sentido para aquele caso.

Em versões mais novas [é possível usar inicialização em propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108516/101).

No C# 9 é possível até parametrizar a criação de um objeto só com a inicialização via propriedade, mas é outro assunto. veja mais em https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Para a maioria dos casos, tanto faz inicializar na declaração ou no construtor, se você quiser dar um valor padrão. O objeto só passa a existir na memória mesmo na hora que é construído.

Se quiser ser bem pedante, você pode depurar a construção do objeto e vai notar que as propriedades inicializadas na declaração recebem valores antes do início do método construtor que você declarou. Mas isso não tem muito efeito prático.

Com relação a boas práticas: cada caso é um caso, então ao invés de discutir qual forma é mais recomendável, é mais proveitoso conhecer as vantagens e desvantagens de cada forma.

Declarar valores no construtor tem a vantagem de que as coisas tendem a ficar concentradas em um único ponto, ou pelo menos em poucos pontos no caso de múltiplos construtores. Compare:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        this.A = new {};
        this.B = new {};
        this.C = new {};
        this.D = new {};
        // etc., etc.
        this.Z = new {};
    }
}
```

Com:

```
public partial class Foo // Atenção especial para o partial
{
    // 26 propriedades

    public Foo()
    {
        /* Seus colegas perguntaram qual era o valor padrão da propriedade Y
         * e você veio procurar aqui. E você provavelmente abriu este código
         * no github e não em uma IDE. Vou dar uma dica, a declaração está
         * em outro arquivo. Descobrir qual será o seu desafio. Compartilhe
         * se você encontrar em até 60 segundos.
         */

         // Sério, não tem código aqui. Este é um construtor vazio.
    }
}
```

Já inicializar na declaração pode ter lá suas vantagens se você estiver trabalhando com propriedades. Você pode fazer Lazy Loading ("carga preguiçosa"), da seguinte forma:

```
private List<string> _afazeres;
public List<string> Afazeres
{
    get
    {
        if (this._afazeres == null)
        {
            this._afazeres = new List<string>()
            {
                "Programar",
                "Postar no Stack Overflow",
                "Estudar",
                "Beber café até morrer",
                "Fazer tudo de novo"
            }
        }
        return this._afazeres;
    }
    set { this._afazeres = value; }
}
```

Isso garante que sua classe pode ser instanciada sem alocar memória para algum campo - aquele campo só vai ocupar espaço a partir da primeira vez que for acessado. Aqui nós temos uma pequena lista de strings, mas isso poderia ser algum objeto realmente pesado.

Answer (score -2):

### Vantagem de Inicializar na Declaração

[Como foi dito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/198193/68989), "Inicializar na Declaração" não é realmente o que acontece, mas vou usar esse termo nesta resposta.
Se você inicializar na Declaração fica mais fácil saber o que há na variável quando a instância é criada, pois é só encontrar a Declaração da Variável.
Esta é a *Solução mais Simples*.

---

### Com Construtores você pode fazer mais

Com um Construtor você pode definir o conteúdo da variável **dinamicamente** na criação da instância, através de diferentes Construtores que atribuem coisas diferentes para a variável e/ou através de Parâmetros no Construtor que serão usados para definir o valor da variável.

Portanto, Construtores te dão maior flexibilidade ao definir o conteúdo da variável quando a instância é crida, mas, aumentam a *Complexidade*.

---

### Desvantagens de usar Construtores

- Se você tiver vários Construtores, cada um definido um valor diferente para a variável, você precisará saber qual Construtor foi utilizado para criar a Instância para saber o que há na variável quando a Instância foi criada. Isto dificulta o debug.
- Se o valor da variável é definido através de um Parâmetro em um Construtor, você precisará saber o que foi passado por este Parâmetro para saber o que há na variável quando a instância foi criada. Isto também dificulta o debug.
- A Complexidade do projeto e a quantidade de código aumenta ao declarar Construtores, isso pode tornar seu projeto mais difícil de entender (pois haverá mais código para estudar).

---

### Conclusão

Utilize Construtores apenas quando for realmente *necessário*, caso contrário você estará criando *Complexidade Desnecessária*. Se você sabe que não precisará do(s) Construtor(es) que está pensando em criar, não crie-os, Inicialize na Declaração.