# Inicialização de atributos

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, inicialização

Existe alguma diferença entre inicializar um atributo assim:

```
public class Turma {

    private List<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<Aluno>();
}
```

Ou assim:

```
public class Turma {

    private List<Aluno> alunos;

    //Considerando que este é o único construtor
    public Turma() {
        alunos = new ArrayList<Aluno>();
    }
}
```

?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198190/28595

Comment: @diegofm essa é C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por debaixo dos panos não há diferenças. No final das contas a instanciação do atributo vai ser colocada dentro do construtor de qualquer forma.

Porém, no primeiro caso, é impossível fazer tratamento de exceções ou qualquer outra operação que seja necessária para trabalhar o valor a ser colocado no atributo.

Ainda assim isso não quer dizer que a inicialização destes atributos precise ser feita nos construtores. É possível criar um bloco de inicialização. Como, por exemplo:

```
public class Turma {
   private ArrayList<Aluno> alunos;

    { // bloco de inicialização
        try {
            alunos = new ArrayList<Aluno>();
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            // Fazer algo
        }
    }
}
```

Da mesma forma que é possível usar o bloco de inicialização, é possível criar um método para instanciar os atributos, tanto os de instância quanto os estáticos.

[Na documentação do Java tem uma seção que fala um pouco sobre isto.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Outra diferença (óbvia, diga-se de passagem) é que se instanciar direto no atributo, você pode criar vários outros construtores e este campo sempre será inicializado, no outro caso será necessário instanciar o atributo em todos os construtores ou fazer algo relativo a isso.

Obs.: Eu falo em "**instanciar**" os atributos durante a resposta, mas tudo o que foi dito também vale para variáveis que não sejam objetos, ou seja, vale também para "colocar o valor" de uma variável.